# Make a Batch program get and use a Google Drive file

Tags: batch-file, google-drive-api

Im programing a Game launcher in batch that starts up other programs ive made, in order to keep the game list and other things accurate, i want my batch file to acess google drive and get information off a text page, Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be possible with pure batch. You could possibly do it with Powershell or used a 3rd party utility.

Comment: Do you know of any 3rd party utils. that could do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Efficient File Management using Batch Requests with Google Apps Script this on https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script

OR

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance?hl=id#batch-example-request